# CakePHP 3.8.6: Authentication does not prevent multiple logins even if no logout done

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

I have followed the [CMS Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/installation.html) step by step and everything was working fine up until I added the code for Login/Authentication. After adding the [login code](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html), (I have edited the existing Password to use DefaultPasswordHasher and created a new user) I am able to login, say as `user1`, then, without logging out (logout code is already there), if I attempt to login by going to

```
localhost:8765/users/login
```

and login as `user2`, it allows me to do so, it should rather say something like 'User1 is already logged in' and redirect me to the default page.

I find that weird b'coz as far as my understanding goes, it uses the current logged in user => no multiple logins should be allowed, but the Auth component does not check if a user is already logged in. In effect, there is nothing preventing me from opening multiple tabs on my browser and loging in as, as many users as I want, as long as those users are in the Database!

Also, when I call the logout page

```
localhost:8765/users/logout
```

it logs out all the logged in users, I guess b'coz it calls  `$this->Auth->logout();` for the current logged in user!
Although, I hav'nt called the logout page for user1, say, and I have called logout for user2, both are logged out, I have to login as user1 again!

So, here is my question: How do I handle the case when a user is already logged in and login page is requested again? How do I handle the case of simultaneous multiple user logins?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really be logged in as multiple users at the same time, at least not out of the box, logging in while you're already logged in, will overwrite / merge with the previously identified user data, and renew the session if you're using the session storage. So while you can continue in your other tabs, you're not authenticated as the same user anymore. However the storage contents in general will not be cleared out, so that might cause issues.

Prevent logging in while you're already logged in is something that you'll have to handle in your application code. In your login action you could for example check for a logged in user before running your code that identifies a user and persists it, something like:

```php
if ($this->Auth->user()) {
    $this->Flash->error('You are already logged in.');

    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}
```

Maybe it would be reasonable for the component to clear at least the specific key before writing to the storage, but that still wouldn't prevent logging in or remove possible state from the "previous" session, that's something you'd still have to take care of yourself.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Accessing the Logged In User](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)**